# Newer version / replacement of BackgroundWorker class?

Tags: wpf, backgroundworker, task-parallel-library

I've been using the .Net BackgroundWorker class to provide a responsive UI in my WPF applications.  It works fine, and I'm happy to continue with it, but I wondered if Microsoft had something in more recent versions of .Net (in the TPL possibly?) that it recommends going forward for best practices or guidance?

Comment: I gave a +1 to Thiru. And with Metro asynch is more prominent.  It looks like asynch will be more mainstream.  But Metro has not System.Data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Asynchronous Programming in the .NET Framework 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh440482)

Comment: I'd read about the async keyword.  Sounds interesting.  As of right now though there's no true replacement for the BackgroundWorker?